# PowerShell ErrorAction SilentlyContinue NOT working

Tags: powershell

The code below works when path exists but if it encounters a path that does not exits it fails and stops I would like for it to continue bad paths here are expected because server could have been decommed

```
(Get-ChildItem -Filter $SearchString  -Path $RootString -Recurse  | Measure-Object -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count
```

This is my error

```
Get-ChildItem : The network path was not found
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -Filter $SearchString  -Path $RootString -Recurse  | Me ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

How can I write this so it continues if it errors.
I am on PS 5.1.17

Comment: Your `-ErrorAction` parameter is on your `Measure-Object` command, and not your `Get-ChildItem` command. I would guess this means any errors encountered with `Get-ChildItem` are treated normally, and any errors encountered by `Measure-Object` will silently continue since that's where you've placed the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `-ErrorAction` parameter is on your `Measure-Object` command, and not your `Get-ChildItem` command. I would guess this means any errors encountered with `Get-ChildItem` are treated normally, and any errors encountered by `Measure-Object` will silently continue since that's where you've placed the parameter.

This is what I would try next in your testing.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Filter $SearchString -Path $RootString -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object).Count
```

Comment: This didnt work at first I had it there before. But when I took your suggestion and wrapped it around a test-path now it works!

Comment: Glad to hear this helped progress your work.